# Certifications or training for a market maker

Tags: market-making

Are there any schools or certifications that will teach you a "market maker 101" type of course? I was thinking of using some of the FINRA study materials as if I was going to take the Series 57 but it seems like that exam is no longer offered. There must be another certification or something else I can use to learn market making, no?

Comment: what products do you want to market-make? Sure there are some general principles but most skills basically rely on knowing the specific nuances of the particular product very well.

Comment: @Attack68 for the sake of discussion, let's just assume I'm interested in binary markets, like what Nadex offers. But I would still like a broader understanding of market making in general.